# JMeter-Taurus Docker Image Error - "No personal config found, creating one at /.bzt-rc"

Tags: jmeter, dockerfile, drone.io, taurus

I am trying to run a performance test within a Drone pipeline using JMeter-Taurus. I am pulling the latest (stable) image for blazemeter-taurus. However, when running the test in a pipeline the following error is returned.

[image]

This is the contents of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM blazemeter/taurus

RUN apt-get update && \
    python3 -m pip install s3cmd

COPY . /bzt/
COPY config/90-artifacts-dir.json /etc/bzt.d/
COPY config/90-no-console.json /etc/bzt.d/
COPY .bzt-rc /root/.bzt-rc

RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /bzt && \
    sed -i -e '/^assistive_technologies=/s/^/#/' /etc/java-*-openjdk/accessibility.properties

USER 1000

VOLUME ["/bzt"]

WORKDIR /bzt
```

UPDATE:
The "USER 1000" part has been removed. And the following line was added:

RUN chmod +x /bzt

But this is the error message returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/bzt", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bzt/cli.py", line 676, in main
    executor = CLI(parsed_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bzt/cli.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.setup_logging(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bzt/cli.py", line 111, in setup_logging
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(options.log, encoding="utf-8")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1146, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1175, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/bzt/bzt.log'
######## TEST RUN STATUS : 1 #######
cat: /bzt/bzt_artifacts/bzt.log: No such file or directory
cat: /bzt/bzt_artifacts/error.jtl: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/bzt/bzt_artifacts/': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'd be interested if you ever solved this.  Without doing my own dockerfile and using blazemeter/taurus, I get the same error: `File "/usr/local/bin/bzt", line 8, in <module>`...

Comment: I added this command below the last copy: RUN chmod +x /bzt

Answer (score 0):

[Taurus Docker image](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/#Docker-Image) is root-oriented, here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/master/Dockerfile)

I fail to see why Taurus is trying to create its config under `/.bzt-rc`, it may be some this "Drone pipeline" specifics, my expectation is that your test will fail because your user 1000 doesn't have write permissions to `/tmp` folder where Taurus stores its [Artifacts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I included an update within the original ticket. Another thoughts on what could still be causing the permission denied error message?